# Copy-pasting HTML into Anki

Tags: copy-paste

I used to be able to copy and paste a section of a webpage from Safari into [Anki](https://apps.ankiweb.net/#mac) (so for example tables and such will come through). But I don't know what setting I've inadvertently changed whether on the Mac or on Anki, because now I cannot paste the entire HTML anymore. It pastes without any formatting. I've gone through all the preferences various times and still cannot see anything that will make it go back to the previous behavior.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Anki seems to have a quite active support site on https://anki.tenderapp.com/, did you already ask there? See https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2509/9058 for why this might yield better results.